# Android read all elements in talkback

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I am going to develop an app for blind users. 
I would like to have a function that once an Activity is start, Talkback would read all elements on that Activity. 
Is there any ways to force Talkback to read all elements in a single activity?
(The activity would include a Title, a listView, few buttons, and a textView)

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  This is a bad idea, just let talkback users explore your application with gestures like every other app out there.

Comment: You will have to do it yourself without Talkback in order to read out all the screen content.

Answer (score 0):

**To read out elements:**

```
View.announceForAccessibility(text) - for elements in an activity
```

**To read out Activities name:**

```
android:label attribute on the Activity tag in your AndroidManifest
```